# HighCharts xAxis categories over 1000 data not work.

Tags: highcharts

I want to draw basic line chart.

When the data type of x-axis is numerical, 
I can use the following options to draw this chart when the number of x labels is larger than 1000

```
plotOptions: {
line: {
turboThreshold: 2000,
},
series: {
turboThreshold: 2000,
}
}
```

But it seems not work when the data type is categorical and the number of category in x-axis is too large (> 1000 categories)

The link I had tried:

[Test on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am2k9c1t/)

Is there any solution about this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: The problem is that physically you have too many ticks, so set a tickInterval or reduce amount of categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/am2k9c1t/

Code:

```
xAxis: {
        tickInterval:10,
        min:1200,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set tickInterval value in xAxis.

example:

```
xAxis: {
        tickInterval:100
}
```

[Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/am2k9c1t/)